# Responsive website Content width is wider than view port width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Ok so I am working on a small template and trying to learn responsive website developing. I am having an issue when testing to see if it is mobile responsive they state that:

> Content width is wider than viewport width   ▾
>   Viewport width: 320px, Content width: 563px

However I cannot seem to work out from my style-sheet what the issue is?

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  max-width: 1080px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 24px 40px 20px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.call-us {
  padding-right: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.cartImg {
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}


/*MEDIA QUERY at 676 to 808px*/

@media (min-width: 676px) and (max-width: 808px) {
  .logo {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    border: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 676px) and (max-width: 808px) {
  .call-us {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 25%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 676px) and (max-width: 808px) {
  .cartImg {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}


/*MEDIA QUERY at 330 to 456px*/

@media (min-width: 330px) and (max-width: 456px) {
  .call-us {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 45px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 330px) and (max-width: 456px) {
  .cartImg {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}


/*MEDIA QUERY at 279 to 330px*/

@media (min-width: 279px) and (max-width: 330px) {
  .call-us {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 279px) and (max-width: 330px) {
  .cartImg {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial;
}

p {
  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

.styleBottomRed {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  background-color: #204393;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab_content_main {
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.prod-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 8px auto;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
  clear: both;
  border: none;
}

.bottomTabs {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 55px;
  max-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #204393;
}

#iconImg {
  float: right;
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.bottomTabsUL,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: square;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}


/*MEDIA QUERY at 866 to 2000px hide different content and show other*/

@media screen and (min-width: 866px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
  .bottomTabs {
    display: none;
  }
  /* hide it elsewhere */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 866px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
  .bottomTabsUL,
  {
    display: none;
  }
  /* hide it elsewhere */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 866px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
  .tdMobile {
    display: none;
  }
  /* hide it elsewhere */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 866px) {
  section {
    display: none;
  }
  /* hide it elsewhere */
}


/*TAB CSS*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 0;
  color: white;
}

section:after {
  content: 'your message goes here';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 45px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 8px 20px 20px 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 125px;
  color: black;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 199px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #204393;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .25s ease;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 145px;
}

.divTab:focus button,
button:focus {
  background-color: #EE2725;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.tabP {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

button:focus+.tabP,
.divTab:focus P {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: none;
  top: 29px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.divTab {
  display: inline-block;
}

.divTab:focus {
  outline: none;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table caption {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: .5em 0 .75em;
}

table tr {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 0px;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

table th {
  font-size: .85em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #204393;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table caption {
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  table thead {
    border: none;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }
  table tr {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td:before {
    /*
                    * aria-label has no advantage, it won't be read inside a table
                    content: attr(aria-label);
                    */
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">

    <a href="http://" target="_blank"><img class="logo" alt="Store" title="Store" src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=Logo" /></a>

    <div class="header-right">
      <a href="tel:0000000000"><img class="call-us" alt="Call Us" title="Call Us" src="http://placehold.it/100x30?text=Call+Us" /></a>
      <a href="http://" target="_blank"><img class="cartImg" alt="Cart Image" title="CartImg" src="http://placehold.it/40x40?text=Cart" /></a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>
  <div class="main">
    <hr>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

    <hr>
    <center><img class="prod-img" src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=Product+Image" width="20%" /></center>
    <hr>

    <p>{{ description }}</p>

    <ul>
      <li>CONTENT GOES HERE</li>
    </ul>

    <table>
      <tbody>
        <caption>Specification</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Model</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Weight</th>
            <th scope="col">Platform Height</th>
            <th scope="col">Overall Height</th>
            <th scope="col">Width</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Model">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Size">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Weight">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Platform Height">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Overall Height">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Width">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

    <br>

    <!--Footer tabs for selecting payment, delivery, returns and warranty.-->
    <section>
      <div class="divTab">
        <button>Payment</button>
        <p class="tabP">CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="divTab">
        <button>Delivery</button>
        <p class="tabP">CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>

      </div>
      <div class="divTab">
        <button>Returns</button>
        <p class="tabP">CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="divTab">
        <button>Warranty</button>
        <p class="tabP">CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
      </div>
    </section>


    <!--Footer tabs for Mobile application compatibility. selecting payment, delivery, returns and warranty.-->
    <table style="width:100%; text-align:center;">

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomTabs">Payment</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMobile" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomTabs">Delivery</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMobile" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
          <ul class="bottomTabsUL">
            <li>CONTENT GOES HERE.</li>
            <li>CONTENT GOES HERE.</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomTabs">Returns</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMobile" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomTabs">Warranty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMobile" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Issue**

Ok so I decided to test and take parts out and noticed that the table was causing the issue. However, what I do not understand is I have table properties set in the style sheet that makes it compatible with responsive web.

```
<table>
      <tbody>
        <caption>Specification</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Model</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Weight</th>
            <th scope="col">Platform Height</th>
            <th scope="col">Overall Height</th>
            <th scope="col">Width</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Model">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Size">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Weight">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Platform Height">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Overall Height">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Width">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have only given the CSS code. Can you give your HTML markup?

Comment: What content has width 563px? could you be more specific what your issue is, there are a bunch of css rules only.

Comment: Learn how to ask question on this site https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: we can't see the problem if you don't share html. However , i suggest you start using bootstrap if you want responsive design

Comment: @SimrandeepSingh  Sorry I just uploaded the HTML

Comment: Just use % instead of px

Comment: Those are really bad values for `media-queries`

Comment: 1/ In DevTools, remove a bunch of elements until the horizontal scrollbar disappears. Last removed one is a good candidate. Refresh and remove that one: is the problem already solved? 2/ You can also add a bunch of background colors and dotted/dashed outlines to your blocks to better diagnose the problem. 3/ Finally, you can read [The difference between width:auto and width:100%](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/) (often times, one writes `width: 100%` when s·he really means `auto`)

Comment: Have you added a `meta` tag similar to this in the top of your site? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: @JamieBarker Yes I have already added that in my code at the top

Comment: I think I will have to just test certain areas of the code and see what is causing this issue and possibly change px with % on most cases. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: see my answer below. it should solve your issue

Comment: @MihaiT thank you for the solution it does work, however my solution above, if you view the snippet and view in full page. if you minimise and scale to 300px and below the way I have done it is mobile compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because of the table. it cannot shrink more

you have a couple of solutions

1. decrease `td` font-size ( but this won't work if you have many columns )
2. you can wrap the table inside a div, give that div overflow scroll and max width 100vw ( optionally you can show a text on mobile saying : ' scroll right or rotate your device to see full table )

see below snippet with solution 2  or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt7kjwvr/)

let me know if it works :D cheers

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  max-width: 1080px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 24px 40px 20px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}

.call-us {
  padding-right: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.tablewrapper { max-width:100vw;overflow-y:scroll}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
h3.showOnMobile { display:none;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">

    <a href="http://" target="_blank"><img class="logo" alt="Store" title="Store" src="http://placehold.it/350x150?text=Logo" /></a>

    <div class="header-right">
      <a href="tel:0000000000"><img class="call-us" alt="Call Us" title="Call Us" src="http://placehold.it/100x30?text=Call+Us" /></a>
      <a href="http://" target="_blank"><img class="cartImg" alt="Cart Image" title="CartImg" src="http://placehold.it/40x40?text=Cart" /></a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <hr>
  <div class="main">
    <hr>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

    <hr>
    <center><img class="prod-img" src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=Product+Image" width="20%" /></center>
    <hr>

    <p>{{ description }}</p>

    <ul>
      <li>CONTENT GOES HERE</li>
    </ul>
  <div class="tablewrapper">
    <h3 class="showOnMobile">scroll right or rotate your device to see full table</h3>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <caption>Specification</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Model</th>
            <th scope="col">Size</th>
            <th scope="col">Weight</th>
            <th scope="col">Platform Height</th>
            <th scope="col">Overall Height</th>
            <th scope="col">Width</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td data-label="Model">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Size">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Weight">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Platform Height">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Overall Height">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
          <td data-label="Width">CONTENT GOES HERE</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

    <br>

    <!--Footer tabs for selecting payment, delivery, returns and warranty.-->
    <section>
      <div class="divTab">
        <button>Payment</button>
        <p class="tabP">CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="divTab">
        <button>Delivery</button>
        <p class="tabP">CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>

      </div>
      <div class="divTab">
        <button>Returns</button>
        <p class="tabP">CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="divTab">
        <button>Warranty</button>
        <p class="tabP">CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
      </div>
    </section>


    <!--Footer tabs for Mobile application compatibility. selecting payment, delivery, returns and warranty.-->

   
 
    <table style="width:100%; text-align:center;">

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomTabs">Payment</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMobile" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomTabs">Delivery</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMobile" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
          <ul class="bottomTabsUL">
            <li>CONTENT GOES HERE.</li>
            <li>CONTENT GOES HERE.</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomTabs">Returns</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMobile" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="bottomTabs">Warranty</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdMobile" style="text-align: left;">
          <p>CONTENT GOES HERE.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the thing is the way I coded the table was mobile compatiable. If you see me code snippet above and view in full page you can see when you minimise the screen it collapses. So I cannot see why it wont see it as responsive.

Comment: @Whitena yes. in your example everything looks ok. what do you mean by content ? i can't see it . also the `wrapper` is ok in width . you have no side scroll no nothing . what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: when I say content I meant inside the table at 260px you can see the same content. The problem I am getting is when i take out the table on responsive web checker it will show that it is responsive and when I place the table in the html the content width is larger than the viewport 320px. I am very confused as to why it is telling me this.

Comment: i cannot replicate your problem...can you replicate it in a fiddle or snippet ? with your code everything works fine

Comment: I have the snippet in my question above, if you open the snippet it will show the table and when it reaches 600px below it will change. But for some reason in responsive design it does not change the code on the media query for the table